Installing pyvista on spyder without anaconda (+ anaconda won't open, Qt error)
I don't think "install" is the right word, but anyway I need to use it for an upcoming exam, in three days. College computers don't have 'anaconda' installed.
I could use my personnal computer but 'anaconda' won't open, I always get the message error "no Qt platform plugin could be initialized". I didn't have it before, it happens since I closed 'anaconda' once (the same way I always do), and since then I can't open 'Spyder' through 'anaconda'.
I looked on the internet and couldn't find anything to help.
